# Upload large SQL database to Azure Table Storage

Tags: .net, sql, azure, cloud, azure-storage

I have a single database table with 10 fields and over 30 million rows. This is ideal for table storage as I only need to search on one column, but return the rest.

I have written a program which takes the rows from the database and uploads to table storage, but at this rate it will take a minimum of 9 or 10 days to complete.

Is there a quick way to upload a complete table to azure Table storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Storage Studio, which is a commmercial package from Cerebrata, has this functionality built in. I believe they will multithread the upload, though I haven't specifically checked. It will still take a while over the internet.

Probably the fastest thing you could do would be to upload the raw data to BLOB storage, and write a WorkerRole that could run in the same data center that would read the blob and write it into table storage. With lots of threads and a good partitioning strategy you could go pretty fast. But the time to implement that might be greater than the savings from just doing it the "slow" way.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tips you can try to improve your performance http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/d84ba34b-b0e0-4961-a167-bbe7618beb83

Comment: Whilst this is great and helps the speed a slight amount, I would still like a bullet proof, "here is my table / csv file" and here is my class definition, go and import it.

Answer (score 1):

You get the best performance from within the datacenter.  If you truly have that much data, it is probably worth the effort to compress it all as a blob, upload the blob into storage, then have a role running in the same datacenter download, decompress, and insert the contents.  It will be orders of magnitude faster than trying that remotely.

If you can also order the data by partition key, you can insert the data in batches (100 entries or 4MB worth) at a time.  You can also parallelize it on batches.

I don't know of anything that will do this for you out of box, so you are going to likely have to write this yourself right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stored procedure i wrote that lets you load very large datasets. You'd have to do it one table at a time and has some caveats but with this i uploaded 7GB or about 10 million rows in 10 minutes.

More info in the code project article i created here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/773469/Automating-Upload-of-Large-Datasets-to-SQL-Azure

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Document Title:  usp_BulkAzureInsert.sql
    Script Purpose:  Dynamically insert large datasets into Azure

    Script Notes:    1) This assumes the current user has write access to the C drive for file copy
                        If the current windows user does not have access override by hardcoding in an export folder location
                        Leave ExportFolder as 'NULL' for C:\User\CurrentUser\AzureExports
                     2) User must have permission to create permanent tables (dropped at the end of the script but used for staging)

    Parameters: @DB_Schema_Table   = DatabaseName.Schema.TableName (3 part no server)
                @AzureTableName    = DatabaseName.Schema.TableName (3 part no server)
                @AzureServer       = Azure Server location ending in .net (no HTTP)
                @AzureClusteredIDX = Azure requires each table to have a clustered index. Comma delimited index definition.
                @AzureUserName     = Azure User Name
                @AzurePassword     = Azure Password
                @ExportFolder      = 'NULL' defaults to C:\User\CurrentUser\AzureExports - Use this to override
                @CleanupDatFiles   = Set to 1 to delete the directory and files created in the upload process
                @ViewOutput        = Set to 1 to view insert information during upload              

        --Sample Execution
        EXECUTE usp_BulkAzureInsert
                @DB_Schema_Table   = 'MyDatabase.dbo.Customers',
                @AzureTableName    = 'AZ001.dbo.Customers',
                @AzureServer       = 'abcdef123.database.windows.net', 
                @AzureClusteredIDX = 'CustomerID, FirstName, LastName',
                @AzureUserName     = 'AzureUserName',
                @AzurePassword     = 'MyPassword123',
                @ExportFolder      = 'NULL',
                @CleanupDatFiles   =  1,
                @ViewOutput        =  1

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    IF OBJECT_ID ( N'usp_BulkAzureInsert', N'P' ) IS NOT NULL
    DROP   PROCEDURE usp_BulkAzureInsert;
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE usp_BulkAzureInsert                 
            @DB_Schema_Table    NVARCHAR(100),
            @AzureTableName     NVARCHAR(100),
            @AzureClusteredIDX  NVARCHAR(100),
            @AzureServer        NVARCHAR(100),
            @AzureUserName      NVARCHAR(100),
            @AzurePassword      NVARCHAR(100),
            @ExportFolder       NVARCHAR(100),
            @CleanupDatFiles    BIT,
            @ViewOutput         BIT
    AS

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Start with Error Checks
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    IF ( SELECT CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(value, value_in_use)) FROM  sys.configurations WHERE  name = N'xp_cmdshell' ) = 0
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('ERROR: xp_cmdshell is not enable on this server/database',16,1)
            RETURN
        END

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Declare and Set Script Variables
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    IF ( @ViewOutput = 1 )
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
        END

    DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(1000), @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @i TINYINT = 1, @NTILE VARCHAR(10), @NTILE_Value TINYINT, @TempTableName VARCHAR(1000), 
            @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX), @TableName VARCHAR(100), @Server NVARCHAR(100)

    --Set the export folder to the default location if the override was not used
    IF @ExportFolder = 'NULL'
        BEGIN
            SET @ExportFolder = N'C:\Users\' + 
                                CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(SYSTEM_USER), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(SYSTEM_USER))-1)) AS VARCHAR(100)) + 
                                N'\AzureExports';
        END;

        --Set a permanent obejct name based on 
        SET @TempTableName = ( LEFT(@DB_Schema_Table, CHARINDEX('.',@DB_Schema_Table)-1) + 
                               '.dbo.TempAzure' +
                               CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@DB_Schema_Table), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@DB_Schema_Table))-1)) AS VARCHAR(100)) )

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Calculate the amount of files to split the dataset into (No more than 250,000 lines per file)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        SET @SQL = ' SELECT @NTILE = CEILING((CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) / 250000)) FROM ' + @DB_Schema_Table +'; ';       

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@NTILE VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT', @NTILE = @NTILE  OUTPUT;     
        SET @NTILE_Value = CAST(@NTILE AS TINYINT);

        SET @TableName = CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@DB_Schema_Table), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@DB_Schema_Table))-1)) AS VARCHAR(100));
        SET @Server = ( SELECT @@SERVERNAME );

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Create a folder to stage the DAT files in
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    --Remove the directory if it already exists and was not previously deleted
    SET @CMD = N'rmDir /Q /S ' + @ExportFolder;
    EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @CMD, NO_OUTPUT;

    --Create a folder to hold the export files
    SET @CMD = N' mkDir ' + @ExportFolder;
    EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @CMD, NO_OUTPUT;

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Create a staging table that breaks the file into sections based on the NTILE_Value
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        --Find the names of the columns in the table
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#ColumnNames') IS NOT NULL
        DROP   TABLE #ColumnNames
        CREATE TABLE #ColumnNames
        (
            ColumnOrder INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            ColumnName  NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
        );
            INSERT  INTO #ColumnNames
            SELECT  COLUMN_NAME
            FROM    information_schema.columns
            WHERE   table_name = @TableName
            ORDER  BY ordinal_position

        --Create a list of the column names
        SELECT @ColumnNames = COALESCE(@ColumnNames + ', ', '') + CAST(ColumnName AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
                              FROM    #ColumnNames;

        --Split the results by the NTILE_Value
        DECLARE @Column1 NVARCHAR(100) = ( SELECT ColumnName FROM #ColumnNames WHERE ColumnOrder = 1 );

        SET @SQL = ' IF OBJECT_ID(''' + @TempTableName + ''') IS NOT NULL
                     DROP   TABLE ' + @TempTableName + '

                     SELECT ' + @ColumnNames + ', ' + '
                            NTILE(' + @NTILE + ') OVER(ORDER BY ' + @Column1 + ') AS NTILE_Value
                     INTO   ' + @TempTableName + '
                     FROM   ' + @DB_Schema_Table
        EXECUTE (@SQL);

        --Now split the dataset into equal sizes creating a DAT file for each batch
        WHILE @i <= @NTILE_Value
            BEGIN

                SET @SQL = 'IF OBJECT_ID(''' + @TempTableName + 'DatFile'') IS NOT NULL
                            DROP   TABLE ' + @TempTableName + 'DatFile 

                            SELECT  ' + @ColumnNames + ' 
                            INTO    ' + @TempTableName + 'DatFile 
                            FROM    ' + @TempTableName + '
                            WHERE   NTILE_Value = ' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(2)) + '

                            CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_TempAzureData ON ' + @TempTableName + 'DatFile ( ' + @AzureClusteredIDX + ' )';
                EXECUTE (@SQL);

                SET @CMD = N'bcp ' + @TempTableName + 'DatFile out ' + 
                    @ExportFolder + N'\' + @TableName + 'DatFile' + 
                    CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(3)) + '.dat -S ' + @Server + ' -T -n -q';

                IF ( @ViewOutput = 1 )
                BEGIN
                    EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @CMD;
                END
                ELSE
                    EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @CMD, NO_OUTPUT;

                SET @i += 1;
            END

        --Clean up the temp tables
        SET @SQL = ' DROP TABLE ' + @TempTableName;
        EXECUTE (@SQL);

        SET @SQL = ' DROP TABLE ' + @TempTableName + 'DatFile' ;
        EXECUTE (@SQL);

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Insert the data into the AzureDB
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        --Reset the Variable
        SET @i = 1;

        --Move each batch file into the DB
        WHILE @i <= @NTILE_Value
            BEGIN               
                SET @CMD = N'Bcp ' + @AzureTableName + ' in ' +
                           @ExportFolder + N'\' + @TableName + 'DatFile' +  CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '.dat -n -U ' +
                           @AzureUserName + '@' + LEFT(@AzureServer, CHARINDEX('.',@AzureServer)-1)  +
                           N' -S tcp:' + @AzureServer +
                           N' -P ' + @AzurePassword;    

                IF ( @ViewOutput = 1 )
                BEGIN
                    EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @CMD;
                END
                ELSE
                    EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @CMD, NO_OUTPUT;

                SET @i += 1;
            END 

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Cleanup the finished tables
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    IF ( @CleanupDatFiles = 1 )
        BEGIN
            SET @CMD = N'rmDir /Q /S ' + @ExportFolder;
            EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @CMD, NO_OUTPUT;
        END

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Script End
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    IF ( @ViewOutput = 1 )
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT OFF;
        END
```

Comment: A great bunch of T-SQL, but it does not answer the question correctly as it deals with uploading to Azure SQL, while question is asking how to upload to Azure Table Storage (NoSQL). Great procedure for uploading to Azure SQL though, or am I missing something?